# Strip unwanted tags from Document

Tags: java, nodes, document

**UPDATE** (Please read below first for context)

I have figured out how to fix the issue below, by simplying calling replaceAll twice on the two different tags, but now I encounter another tag issue:

```
Turn right onto Waialae Ave<div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the left</div>
```

I do not want to make special cases just so that the program will be able to remove all formatting tags not specific to just the bold and style tags. Therefore, is there a way for my program to detect the < symbol and remove everything contained inside it, inclusive of the symbol, up to the end symbol >? That would be very helpful.

---

I am working on using the Google Maps API to provide information to the user; however, when doing so, it prints out the bold formatting tags as shown below:

```
Head <b>northwest</b> toward <b>Kalaniiki St</b>
```

I am trying to strip this by using the replaceAll method:

```
String instructions = eElement.getElementsByTagName("html_instructions").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
instructions = instructions.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ");
```

However, this only gets rid of the < and > symbols and not the character b. How would I change the formatting of the replaceAll method so that it gets rid of boldface tags? Please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: How about using something like JSoup to parse/get the text representation? https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string. Alternatively, does the API expose any way to get plain text instead of html?

Comment: This should do it: `String.replace("<b>", "").replace("</b>", "");` or even `String.replaceAll("<.+?>", "");` which should remove most HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could trying using a regex to capture opening and closing tags and replace them an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plausible way to do this with only the `str.replaceAll()` method. I'll update if I come up with something that only uses that.

The code below works **after** running the `str.replaceAll()` It will grab the remaining text inside html tags. The reason you still need  `str.replaceAll()` is to get rid of things like `&nbsp` etc... I added a space at the start, this will prevent words from being combined. This space may have to be trimmed out later depending on specs.

```
do{
   str += (" " + (str.substring(str.indexOf(">") + 1, str.indexOf("<")); 
} while(str.indexOf("<") != -1);
```